# Expo react app is unresponsive on first load, but works after reopening using Recent button

Tags: android, reactjs, expo

I'm testing out an Expo React app built to APK. Both my smartphone and the emulator it follows are unresponsive on first load. The app becomes responsive once you press the Recents button, and then select the app. Any ideas of how I could address or debug using logcat?